# Why Qt checks for QML app creation in that way?

Tags: qt, qml

When I create a blank QML application in Qt, the IDE automatically creates the main.cpp like below. What I don't understand is why in the if statement it checks for obj and url? why it doesn't just check for obj alone? Why do we need this checking at first place?

```
const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
        QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
engine.load(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [qt-docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#objectCreated):

> `void QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated(QObject *object, const QUrl &url)`
> ...object contains a pointer to the loaded object, otherwise the pointer is NULL.
> The url to the component the object came from is also provided.

So the signal `QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated` passes obj and objUrl to the lambda. In the lambda `obj` is checked for nullptr and `objUrl` is checked if it was created from the correct url.
If one of the two conditions is not met you know the object was not created correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. If everything go OK the objUrl == url is always true. And if for some reason objUrl != url we will never get in to the if statement. So what good is having it there?

Comment: yes, i don't know under which circumstances the url would be other than the one passed to `engine.load(url)` if the object is not null. There might be a case.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need this whole check. It would be enough to check if `obj` is not a null pointer, since that would mean that `load` failed, as states the documentation.

The second check (`url == objUrl`) is superfluous and will never be true. The only way this fails, is if the url to qml file was provided as a `QString`, [because](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#objectCreated):

> Note: If the path to the component was provided as a QString containing a relative path, the url will contain a fully resolved path to the file.

But in that case it wouldn't be a good idea to kill the application.

Feel free to submit a bug to Qt devs :)

Comment: url == objUrl is always true if everything go OK. Despite that, it seems the reason you have provided can be the answer. In that case Let's say someone creates url from QString and for some reason !obj goes true (QML fails the creation), in this case we wont get into the if statement but we should!

Comment: I don't think the author of the code generated by the IDE gave it as much thought as you do. Feel free to modify as you wish.